# Is there any k-Weisfeiler-Lehman graph isomorphism implementation available?

Tags: graphs

Despite the huge number of theoretical articles about k-WL, I can't find any implementation online beside some provably failed attempts:
https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/25802

Is my Google-Fu very bad or is there just no available implementation?